# How to get the particular row always in mysql query with Limit

Tags: php, mysql

I have a sql query for getting first 40 list of users.I want to retrieve one user always in that list.Is their any method in query specifying the user id with the limit

Comment: I guess you need to use `UNION` !!

Answer (score 5):

The best way I can think of is:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE userid='your-user-id' UNION SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE userid!='your-user-id' LIMIT 39
```

Basically, you select your user, and then you select 39 others. You use UNION to conjoin the two SELECT results.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    `users`
WHERE 
    `user_id` != 12345
LIMIT 39
UNION SELECT 
    *
FROM
    `users`
WHERE
    `user_id` = 12345
ORDER BY `user_id`
;
```

This will give you first 39 users + user with user_id=12345.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that would be

```
(SELECT * from users limit 39)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * from users where userid='your-user-id')
```

Comment: This would only select the user with that ID

Comment: So, "to retrieve one user always in that list." doesn't meant that way? It means that the other 39 users (other-user-id) + 1 particular-user-id-always-there?

Comment: I believe the OP wishes to select 40 users, and always have a particular user as part of that selection. This query will only ever select rows with the specified ID

Comment: Then i would suggest to use UNION ALL. The query would be like ( LIMIT 39 of the other user-id) UNION ALL (the-one-user-id). Never tried before and not sure its practical or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from table order by userd_id limit 40
```

Answer (score 0):

As most of the options are already provided, check if this can help you

```
select name from user_details where id = user_id || id != user_id  order by field (id,user_id) desc limit 40;
```

This will give you combine results & if you want your specified user id will always come on top.